# error: 'redisAsyncContext' does not name a type redisAsyncContext *context;

Tags: gcc, redis, embedded-linux, hiredis

i'm getting a very peculiar error when i include libevent.h.
Its not able to find redisAsyncContext struct.
This is my header file

```
#include <hiredis/hiredis.h>
#include <hiredis/async.h>
#include <hiredis/adapters/libevent.h>

class RedisMgr :Thread{
public:
    
    static RedisMgr  *getRedisMgr ();
    int Init();
    void Start();
    int End();
    void* run();

    int Publish(int type);
    
private:
    static RedisMgr s_instance;

    bool exitThread;
    
    redis_t Pub_Redis;
    sem_t redis_publock;

    RedisMgr();
    ~RedisMgr ();

    static void pubCallback(redisAsyncContext *c, void *r, void *privdata);
    void pubCallback_Handler(redisAsyncContext *c, void *r, void *privdata);
    static void connectCallback(const redisAsyncContext *c, int status);
    void connectCallback_Handler(const redisAsyncContext *c, int status);
    static void disconnectCallback(const redisAsyncContext *c, int status);
    void disconnectCallback_Handler(const redisAsyncContext *c, int status);
};
```

The error is thrown from both included file libevent.h and also refisAsyncContext reference i have made in my .h

This is the error:

```
/usr/include/hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:11:5: error: 'redisAsyncContext' does not name a type
     redisAsyncContext *context;

src/headers/RedisMgr.h:36:5: error: 'redisAsyncContext' does not name a type
     redisAsyncContext *c;
```

Comment: This is strange because *redisAsyncContext* is defined in *async.h*. You use the tag *gcc* you mean *g++*. Do you have *redisAsyncContext* defined in the result if you just preprocess `g++ -E ...flags... my.h`  ? Do you use the last release of hiredis ?

Comment: i think i found the problem. Somehow my async.h has been replaced and it does not have redisAsyncContext defined.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
Somehow the async.h was replaced/changed and it no longer had definition of redisAsyncContext struct.
I downloaded the corresponding file from internet and the build just worked fine.
i should have thoroughly checked it prior to posting question- mybad

Comment: for your discharge it is difficult to imagine that someone made such a change akin to sabotage

Comment: I know..god knows how this happened